# rails 3 flash not clearing after redirect to different subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, subdomain, cookiestore

So, I have a controller such as this

```
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  def show
    flash[:notice] = "TEST"
    redirect_to root_path(:subdomain => 'test')
  end
end
```

Additionally, I have this line in my config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
Foo::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_foo_session', :domain => :all
```

My problem is as follows. If I go to http://example.com/something (the route leading to the above controller action), the action correctly sets the flash and redirects to the appropriate subdomain url (http://test.example.com/). The view for that action correctly displays the flash I set in the previous action. However, the flash is NOT cleared after this action - or, for that matter, ANY subsequent action on the subdomain in question - and continues to appear until I manually navigate back to some other URL on the root domain (example.com), at which point the flash is reset and ceases to appear on either domain.

If I try to use

```
flash.now[:notice] = "TEST"
```

instead of

```
flash[:notice] = "TEST"
```

the page at the end of the redirect does not register the existence of the message at all and thus shows nothing.

How can I get the functionality described in the first case above, but such that it behaves as it normally should and clears the flash after the request?